# EF Core Migration error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when migrating two entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-migrations

the problem is the next.

I have two entities, one called Service and other Owner, if i migrate them separately the process build, and create migrations with no problem. But when i tried to create a migration of both entities at the same time gives me an error.

I am trying to learn more about DDD, currently My Objects ids are ValueObjects.

Below ill post the entities with their EFCore configuration and the error stack trace.
**Service Entity**

```
 public sealed class Service : AggregateRoot<ServiceId>
    {
        private readonly List<CustomerId> _customersIds = new();
        private readonly List<PaymentId> _paymentsIds = new();
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }
        public float Price { get; private set; }
        //TODO: enum or list
        public string Currency { get; private set; }
        //TODO: enum
        public string PaymentRegularity { get; private set; }
        public OwnerId OwnerId { get; private set; }

        public IReadOnlyList<CustomerId> CustomersIds => _customersIds.AsReadOnly();
        public IReadOnlyList<PaymentId> PaymentsIds => _paymentsIds.AsReadOnly();

        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; private set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedDateTime { get; private set; }

        private Service(
            ServiceId serviceId,
            string name,
            string description,
            float price,
            string currency,
            string paymentRegularity,
            OwnerId ownerId,
            DateTime createdDateTime,
            DateTime updatedDateTime) : base(serviceId)
        {
            Name = name;
            Description = description;
            Price = price;
            Currency = currency;
            PaymentRegularity = paymentRegularity;
            OwnerId = ownerId;
            CreatedDateTime = createdDateTime;
            UpdatedDateTime = updatedDateTime;
        }

        public static Service Create(
            string name,
            string description,
            float price,
            string currency,
            string paymentRegularity,
            OwnerId ownerId)
        {
            return new Service(
                ServiceId.CreateUnique(),
                name,
                description,
                price,
                currency,
                paymentRegularity,
                ownerId,
                DateTime.UtcNow,
                DateTime.UtcNow);
        }

#pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
        private Service()
        {
        }
#pragma warning restore CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.

    }
```

**Service EFCore Configuration**:

```
public class ServiceConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Service>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Service> builder)
        {
            ConfigureServicesTables(builder);
            ConfigureServiceCustomerIds(builder);
            ConfigureServicPaymentsIds(builder);
        }

        private void ConfigureServicPaymentsIds(EntityTypeBuilder<Service> builder)
        {
            builder.OwnsMany(p => p.PaymentsIds, cId =>
            {
                cId.ToTable("PaymentsIds");

                cId.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("ServiceId");

                cId.HasKey("Id");

                cId.Property(p => p.Value)
                .HasColumnName("PaymentsId")
                .ValueGeneratedNever();
            });

            builder.Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(Service.PaymentsIds))!
                .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
        }

        private void ConfigureServiceCustomerIds(EntityTypeBuilder<Service> builder)
        {
            builder.OwnsMany(p => p.CustomersIds, cId =>
            {
                cId.ToTable("CustomersIds");

                cId.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("ServiceId");

                cId.HasKey("Id");

                cId.Property(p => p.Value)
                .HasColumnName("CustomerId")
                .ValueGeneratedNever();
            });

            builder.Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(Service.CustomersIds))!
                .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
        }

        private void ConfigureServicesTables(EntityTypeBuilder<Service> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Services");

            builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
            builder.Property(p => p.Id)
                .HasConversion(
                    id => id.Value,
                    value => ServiceId.Create(value));

            builder.Property(p => p.Name)
                .HasMaxLength(50);

            builder.Property(p => p.Description)
                .HasMaxLength(100);

            builder.Property(p => p.Price);
            builder.Property(p => p.Currency);
            builder.Property(p => p.PaymentRegularity);

            builder.Property(p => p.OwnerId)
                .HasConversion(
                    id => id.Value,
                    value => OwnerId.Create(value));
        }
    }
```

**Owner Entity**

```
  public sealed class Owner : AggregateRoot<OwnerId>
    {
        private readonly List<ServiceId> _serviceIds = new();
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public IReadOnlyList<ServiceId> ServiceIds => _serviceIds.AsReadOnly();

        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; private set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedDateTime { get; private set; }

        private Owner(
            OwnerId ownerId,
            string name,
            DateTime createdDateTime,
            DateTime updatedDateTime) : base(ownerId)
        {
            Name = name;
            CreatedDateTime = createdDateTime;
            UpdatedDateTime = updatedDateTime; 
        }

        public static Owner Create(string name)
        {
            return new Owner(
                OwnerId.CreateUnique(),
                name,
                DateTime.UtcNow,
                DateTime.UtcNow);
        }

        #pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
        private Owner()
        {
        }
#pragma warning restore CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.

    }
```

**Owner EFCore Configuration**:

```
    public class OwnerConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Owner>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Owner> builder)
        {
            ConfigureOwnerTables(builder);
            ConfigureServiceIds(builder);
        }

        private void ConfigureServiceIds(EntityTypeBuilder<Owner> builder)
        {
            builder.OwnsMany(p => p.ServiceIds, cId =>
            {
                cId.ToTable("ServiceIds");

                cId.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("OwnerId");

                cId.HasKey("Id");

                cId.Property(p => p.Value)
                .HasColumnName("ServiceId")
                .ValueGeneratedNever();
            });

            builder.Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(Owner.ServiceIds))!
                .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
        }

        private void ConfigureOwnerTables(EntityTypeBuilder<Owner> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Owners");

            builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
            builder.Property(p => p.Id)
                .HasConversion(
                    id => id.Value,
                    value => OwnerId.Create(value));

            builder.Property(p => p.Name)
                .HasMaxLength(50);
        }
    }
```

**ERROR:**

````
PM> dotnet ef migrations add InitMigration -p .\PaymentsManager.Infrastructure -s .\PaymentsManager.Api
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionBatchExtensions.Run(IConventionBatch batch, InternalForeignKeyBuilder relationshipBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalForeignKeyBuilder.ReuniquifyImplicitProperties(Boolean force)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ForeignKeyPropertyDiscoveryConvention.DiscoverProperties(IConventionForeignKeyBuilder relationshipBuilder, IConventionContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ForeignKeyPropertyDiscoveryConvention.ProcessForeignKeyRequirednessChanged(IConventionForeignKeyBuilder relationshipBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnForeignKeyRequirednessChanged(IConventionForeignKeyBuilder relationshipBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnForeignKeyRequirednessChangedNode.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.DelayedConventionScope.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Run()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Run(IConventionForeignKey foreignKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.OwnsManyBuilder[TRelatedEntity](TypeIdentity ownedType, MemberIdentity navigation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.OwnsMany[TRelatedEntity](Expression`1 navigationExpression, Action`1 buildAction)
   at PaymentsManager.Infrastructure.Persistance.Configurations.ServiceConfigurations.ConfigureServiceCustomerIds(EntityTypeBuilder`1 builder) in C:\Users\Mimosona\source\repos\PaymentsManager\PaymentsManager.Infrastructure\Persistance\Configurations\ServiceConfigurations.cs:line 39
   at PaymentsManager.Infrastructure.Persistance.Configurations.ServiceConfigurations.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder`1 builder) in C:\Users\Mimosona\source\repos\PaymentsManager\PaymentsManager.Infrastructure\Persistance\Configurations\ServiceConfigurations.cs:line 14
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration[TEntity](IEntityTypeConfiguration`1 configuration)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, Func`2 predicate)
   at PaymentsManager.Infrastructure.Persistance.PaymentsManagerDbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) in C:\Users\Mimosona\source\repos\PaymentsManager\PaymentsManager.Infrastructure\Persistance\PaymentsManagerDbContext.cs:line 19
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, ModelCreationDependencies modelCreationDependencies, Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel(Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__8_4(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.```


Thanks, :D


Tried to ignore the configuration of Owner for ServiceId list and let EFCore to solve it by itself, but with no luck.
````

Comment: Did you had any luck in solving this issue? I have the same EXACT setup (with different class and property names) and I'm getting the same `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. I'm going in circles trying to find out what is the problem here.

I've been following  [this DDD tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_un3PUER8U) and tried to extrapolate the shown configuration to multiple connected aggregates as you did.